# Azure APIM - RBAC Role for approving subscription requests

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rbac

I have azure apim premium instance and I want to provide a specific ad group users with access to approve the subscription requests. How can i give this group read access and subscription approval access rights via RBAC? is there a specific custom rbac permission I should create?

Comment: You can create custom RBAC role by including `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/subscriptions/write` action in allowed permissions along with all read permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one APIM service named **`sriapimdemo`** with below subscriptions in it like this:

[image]

> To *activate/approve* subscription requests, you can create **custom** RBAC by including`Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/subscriptions/write` action with all other read permissions.

I created one custom RBAC role named **Subscription Approver** with below permissions:

***Sample.json:***

```json
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/subId/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/xxxxxxxxx",
    "properties": {
        "roleName": "Subscription Approver",
        "description": "Approves subscriptions in APIM",
        "assignableScopes": [
            "/subscriptions/subId"
        ],
        "permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/*/read",
                    "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/read",
                    "Microsoft.Authorization/*/read",
                    "Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/*",
                    "Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/read",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/*",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read",
                    "Microsoft.Support/*",
                    "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/subscriptions/write"
                ],
                "notActions": [
                    "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/users/keys/read"
                ],
                "dataActions": [],
                "notDataActions": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I assigned this **custom** RBAC role to one user under the APIM resource like this:

[image]

Now, I signed in with that user and clicked on **`Activate`** option of **suspended** subscription:

[image]

When I refreshed the page, subscription **activated** successfully as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Sridevi.  In the assignable scope  "/subscriptions/subId", can i mention a specific subscription id and restrict the approval to a specific subscription?